# Generics and Collections in GWT, Null Pointer

Tags: java, generics, gwt

When calling a method that adds an object to a collection in GWT I get a null pointer error.  I have no idea why as everything I have done creates a very simple object (only contains a string).  Here is the code that calls the function and the function:

```
public class PlantMenu extends VerticalPanel {

    private Collection<PlantData> plantList;
    private Collection<PlantData> newPlantData;

    public PlantMenu() {
        createPlants();
        /*
        for(Iterator<PlantData> i = plantList.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Window.alert(i.next().getPlantName());
        }*/
    }

    public Collection<PlantData> createPlants() {
        PlantData plant1 = new PlantData("Herbs");
        PlantData plant2 = new PlantData("Flowers");
        PlantData plant3 = new PlantData("Vegetable");

        newPlantData.add(plant1);
        newPlantData.add(plant2);
        newPlantData.add(plant3);
        return newPlantData;
    }

}
```

It errors out (null pointer) when trying to add the first plant, this line:

PlantData plant1 = new PlantData("Herbs");

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: If Vinegar's answer is not correct, then you haven't given us enough information to help you.  If his answer does not help, then you need to give us the stack dump and more information.

Comment: It would seem that there is a problem in the PlantData constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't initialize your collections. Despite, you already told that its not on that line, but I doubt it. Showing a full exception stack would be much more helpful though. And the exception may occur in your PlantData constructor, but you didn't show it here.

You could do something like this,

```
private Collection<PlantData> plantList = new ArrayList<PlantData>();
private Collection<PlantData> newPlantData = new ArrayList<PlantData>();
```

I have used ArrayList, because generally we use ArrayList. Other implementation can also be used, according to the requirements.

Comment: Ok, so I can't initialize a collection of collections?  Tried that, doesn't appear to work.  It has to be some other type of subclass of a collection?

Comment: May be we can give you a better idea. Show us the code and elaborate what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: private Collection<PlantData> plantList = new Collection<PlantData>();
does not work right?  That's about all, I think I was misunderstanding the application of Collections.

Comment: I'm using an ArrayList and it works out fine, I can initialize one like so: private ArrayList<PlantData> plantList = new ArrayList<PlantData>(); and it works fine.

Comment: Collection is an interface, you can't instantiate it directly like that. Moreover, its good to have Collection or List on the left hand side. I mean program-to-interface-not-implementation. Instantiate the ArrayList, but have it in the Collection or List, as I showed above.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialised your variables properly, this has nothing to do with GWT and is just basic Java. Here's a working version:

```
public class PlantMenu extends VerticalPanel {

    private List<PlantData> plantList = new ArrayList<PlantData>();
    private List<PlantData> newPlantData = new ArrayList<PlantData>();

    public PlantMenu() {
        createPlants();
        for(PlantData plant : newPlantData) {
                Window.alert(plant.getPlantName());
        }
    }

    public List<PlantData> createPlants() {
        newPlantData.add(new PlantData("Herbs"));
        newPlantData.add(new PlantData("Flowers"));
        newPlantData.add(new PlantData("Vegetable"));
        return newPlantData;
    }

}
```

As a side note, you shouldn't be extending VerticalPanel, but rather extending Composite and then using a vertical panel as your widget using setWidget(...);